# Add and remove items by index when pushed into state array with other array data React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to remove items from an array that are pushed into a state array. I can add but the remove is slightly confusing for me in terms of react. Current remove function does not work as it removes all, but the first element? I only want to be able to remove the added data e.g. 5,6,7,8

Stackblitz: https://react-ts-p6iwoh.stackblitz.io

Code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

interface Idata {
  name: string;
  values: number[];
}

const initialData: Idata[] = [
  {
    name: 'Title 1',
    values: [98, 15, 7, 8],
  },
  {
    name: 'Title 2',
    values: [44, 5, 7, 8],
  },
  {
    name: 'Title 3',
    values: [5, 7, 8, 9],
  },
  {
    name: 'Title 4',
    values: [76, 88, 9, 5],
  },
];

const addData: Idata[] = [
  {
    name: 'Title 5',
    values: [98, 15, 7, 8],
  },
  {
    name: 'Title 6',
    values: [44, 5, 7, 8],
  },
  {
    name: 'Title 7',
    values: [5, 7, 8, 9],
  },
  {
    name: 'Title 8',
    values: [76, 88, 9, 5],
  },
];

const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [tag, setTag] = React.useState<Idata[]>(initialData);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="intial-data">
        {tag?.map((inner: Idata, index: number) => {
          return <div key={index}>{inner.name}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        {addData?.map((inner: Idata, index: number) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <div>
                {inner.name}{' '}
                <button
                  onClick={() =>
                    setTag((oldArray) => [...oldArray, addData[index]])
                  }
                >
                  Add
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() =>
                    setTag((oldArray) => oldArray.splice(index, 1))
                  }
                >
                  Remove
                </button>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the comments below:

After you add an `id` to `IData`, you could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like:

```
onClick={() =>
    setTag((oldArray) => {
        return oldArray.filter(item => item.id !== inner.id);
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried that in the stackblitz example and that does not work?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work". It will update the array as described. Though it could be that that updated value is not what you're looking for.

Comment: If you add the code you suggested, it does not delete the items, I only want to delete the items that are added i.e. 5,6,7,8

Comment: Ah, so you don't actually don't want to *delete by index* but rather every added item that matches the one where *remove* was clicked?

Comment: Correct, sorry maybe worded wrong but I thought it would be by index

Comment: It's ok! I don't think the index is any good here. You'll need another form of identity. Have you considered adding an `id` to `Idata`? Otherwise you'd need to define when two elements are equal.

Comment: Yes I can add in id to Idata, you can update the stackblitz with your example?

Comment: Can you just explain why use filter, I know we are filtering by id? also is it based on anything unique so even the name could be used?

Comment: Yeah, something along those lines. Ultimately you'll need a way to identify the elements. Whether that is via a surrogate id (for example an id property with some unique value), or in this case the `name` property is up to you and depends on your project. Though once you have established how you identify the elements, you can simply filter on that property. So for example, if `name` is unique, you could also do: `return oldArray.filter(item => item.name !== inner.name);`